# How to use values of build.properties in another property file using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using eclipse for selenium webdriver. I have assigned an URL to the variable 'webdriver.url' in build.properties file. I have created another property file called 'ExpectedResults.properties'. I want to use the value of variable webdriver.url of build.properties in ExpectedResults.properties file. Is it possible to use. If possible can you please tell how it will be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading properties has nothing to do with Selenium! This is a Java problem. Please correct your tags. Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear whats the objective is. Two cases are possible here -

1.Assuming you have url in 'webdriver.url' variable.
You can write it to second property file ('ExpectedResults.properties') as

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    output = new FileOutputStream("ExpectedResults.properties");
    prop.setProperty("expected.url", webdriver.url);
    prop.store(output, null);

} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

2 You can read both property files & compare URLs -

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

InputStream input = null;
try {

input = new FileInputStream("filename.properties");

prop.load(input);

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("webdriver.url"));      
} 

catch (IOException ex) {

ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Here ExpectedResults.properties is a text file. The value I have given is as "webdriver.url = http://www.google.com". My objective is to use this value in ExpectedResults.properties text file. Is the 1st case is possible to use in ExpectedResults.properties text file?

Comment: By the name(ExpectedResults.properties) it looks like it is property file. Though it is text file it will contain values in form key=value.

And yes ,first case is possible here . You can set url value in 'ExpectedResults.properties' file as given in point1 above. 

Later on you can use url the value you have set in 'ExpectedResults.properties' by reading file as given in point2 above